# How to disable fragment for portrait mode or for phone

Tags: android, android-layout

I am Using fragments in my android application, it looks good in tablet but I don't want fragment in phone so is there any way to disable fragments for phone?
Instead of fragment i want to show normal activity on phone but when you on tablet than fragment should displayed.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can have different versions of the same screen depending on the size and density. So for example say you have a main.xml, there can be one for phones, tablets of 7 inches, 10 inches, etc. The only difference that instead of putting the tablet version main.xml in res/layout, you put it in res/layout-xlarge for example. An now in your regular res/layout you can use Activities, and in res/layout-xlarge you can use Fragments instead. Check out the [android](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) docs on this for more info as it is a little more complicated now than it was. But this should give you the effects you are looking for.

Comment: ok so according to you it is possible to have fragments only for tablet and you can have normal view for phone..thanks a lot

Comment: Yes. Look at the link I sent you. It has the info. Please note though, that your java files will still be the same, meaning you will have to check what the screen size is to correctly use Activity or Fragment. But to be honest, you should just use Fragments for both. Just lay it out differently using the different xml files. This way you only deal with fragments.